# Unable to Format DHCPLeaseObtained from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration with DateTime

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, format

Having a bit of trouble finding a good solution with storing some data from `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` as `DateTime` format. It is beginning to annoy.

Sometimes I am getting a cannot bind error. Sometimes it says cannot convert.

This is what is stored in `DHCPLeaseObtained`. Microsoft's [Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) for the class says it is already `DateTime` but `Get-Member` and `.GetType()` say it is a `String`

```
19700101001541.000000-300
```

I have tried wrapping it in `Get-Date` before and after messing with substrings with no success. Have also tried the following with no success

```
$NewDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact(($Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained), 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
```

Example code to get the data with the complicated way I am currently using to make the date readable

```
$Adapter_Data = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter |
    Where-Object {$_.NetConnectionStatus -EQ 2} | 
    Select-Object Index

foreach ($Row in $Adapter_Data) {
    $Configuration_Data = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
        Where-Object {$_.Index -eq $Row.Index} |
        Select-Object DHCPLeaseObtained    
}

$Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained

$After = (
    $Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained.Substring(0,4) +
    $Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained.Substring(4,2) +
    $Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained.Substring(6,2) +
    $Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained.Substring(8,2) +
    $Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained.Substring(10,2)
)

$After
```

Any help or ideas on a simpler solution to get it in `DateTime` would be appreciated.

Comment: use the CIM cmdlet to get the info and you will get a proper `[datetime]` object. it's one of the many ways that CIM cmdlets are nicer than WMI cmdlets. [*grin*]

Comment: I will look into this. I have never used CIM cmdlets before. Always nice to learn something new

Comment: they CIM stuff is _usually_ faster, plus it _usually_ gives date or time info in standard `[datetime]` object format. quite nice! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already see that the datetime format is a little odd, *“year-month-day-hour-minute-second"*.

The easiest way to convert dates in this format is with the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class as follows:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject –Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$os.ConvertToDateTime($Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained)
```

So your full code snippet:

```
$Adapter_Data = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter |
    Where-Object {$_.NetConnectionStatus -EQ 2} | 
    Select-Object Index

foreach ($Row in $Adapter_Data) {
    $Configuration_Data = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
        Where-Object {$_.Index -eq $Row.Index} |
        Select-Object DHCPLeaseObtained    
}

$os = Get-WmiObject –Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$os.ConvertToDateTime($Configuration_Data[0].DHCPLeaseObtained)
```

This will, by default, output a datetime object in the format:

```
01 November 2018 13:30:35
```

The output is a valid datetime object:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                 
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richmac/2011/07/21/wmi-date-formats-powershell-to-the-rescue/

Comment: Not the exact solution I was looking for but it got me in the right direction. `Select-Object @{Name = "DHCPLeaseObtained"; Expression = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.DHCPLeaseObtained)}}` without adding items I would not be using. That link was very helpful.